# Implementing my Javascript function to database query results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've got my `JS function`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function createYoutubeEmbedLink(link){
          return link.replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
                                  "http://www.youtube.com/embed/");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
```

And I'm trying to get it to work with my query what I'm getting from the database

```
            while($songs = mysql_fetch_array($data))
        {
            Print "<b>Name (id): </b>" .$songs['id'] . "</br>";
            Print "<b>Url: </b>" .$songs['url'] . "</br>";
            Print "</br>";
        }
    ?>
```

This will display normal Youtube URLs but I'm trying to add the JS function to it so it would convert it to Youtube Embed video. Where should i put the JS function exactly?

Comment: where are you actually calling the video. In any <a> tags?

Comment: Atm I'm only calling the URL. With this  Print "<b>Url: </b>" .$songs['url'] . "</br>";. It's in string format atm. And now i see a problem already. But yeah, link can be changed to string. But the main problem atm is how to modify the url/string.

Comment: Modified my Print URL line:

    Print "<b>Url: </b> <a href=" .$songs['url'] . ">" .$songs['url'] . "</a></br>";

Comment: If you want to play the embedded video on clicking the url, then call the function in the onclick event of url.

Comment: I don't want to play the embedded video on clicking the url. I don't want an onclick function for it. I would like that the URLs would be converted on load. The embedded code i understand i know how to go on forward after when normal youtube links have been converted to embed URL-s. But i don't understand how i can load my function to do it for the links.

Comment: call the function in $(document).ready(function () {    
    }); or in the load of the <a> tag as $("a").load(function(){});

Comment: Ok found a solution. Removed the JS totally. Used str_replace instead     Print "<b>Url: </b>" .str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','http://www.youtube.com/embed/', $songs['url']). "</br>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found a solution. Removed the JS totally. Used str_replace instead Print "    **Url:** " .str_replace('youtube.com/watch?v=','http://www.youtube.com/embed/    …;, $songs['url']). "";